# Android - Combination of Translate & Scale Layout

Tags: android, animation

Hello I wouldlike to have animation from left to right , It should streatch portion from left to right , I have layout like this : http://postimg.org/image/vzjx7w5l3/ . When user clicks on Black area then it should stretch image like http://postimg.org/image/anp3efuyr/ .

I have tried following xmls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"       
  android:fromXDelta="1000"
  android:toXDelta="0"
  android:fromYDelta="0"
  android:toYDelta="0" 
  android:duration="2000"
  android:fillAfter="true" />
```

The above only move view from right to left only.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
   android:fillAfter="true">
<translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%p"
     android:toXDelta="75%p"
     android:duration="800" />
```

The above only move from Right to left but donet stretch portrion

I have used combination :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="0%p"
      android:toXDelta="75%p"
      android:duration="800" />
 <scale
     android:duration="500"
     android:fromXScale="1.0"
     android:fromYScale="1.0"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     android:toXScale="1.0"
     android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

The above code move whole view to North East.

I am new to animation. Any help will be appricoated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to scale the view using fromXScale and toXScale.

```
<scale
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="1000" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it showing same effect. the whole black layout going toward North East.

Comment: Did you use a combination? Just use scale.

Comment: Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animate);
view.startAnimation(animation);

Comment: Now used this https://pastee.org/xtf2u , But layout black portion moves from Left to Right.

Comment: It seems like it stretch portion as well as moving to Right

Comment: This is my animate.xml https://pastee.org/bqchg It doesn't move. Because only scale it.

Comment: Hey its a working , i also found the way , Just increase  android:pivotY="45%" . But i dont know why animation layout should be top when layout stretch but here it showing image portion like http://postimg.org/image/m4ze1dz1v/